# Positioning entire wrapper (div) inside of a main wrapper ( div )

Tags: html, css, position, positioning, wrapper

I currently have a site I'm working on ( copying another site as Practice )

This is the site I am trying to re-create 
http://www.north2.net/
.

I am almost done, however I cannot ***position the two side sections(left and right of main image)*** correctly.

Can anyone help me out?

I have 3 "sections" left, middle, right, all are in a wrapper

***I've tried***

margin-top, 
removing inline-block on the wrappers

...

MY GOAL :

Is to be able to raise the two side bars to my liking, but I don't see how to raise them in any way.
north2.net to see what I mean.

***JSFIDDLE***
http://jsfiddle.net/abXk4/

***Not Important ::*** 
Also, when I position anything, my background image moves and there is a white gap on the bottom of the page, my screen is 1920 x 1080, so any adjustment makes a white space,
I've been fixing this with 
padding-bottom: X%;

Is this just something I have to do? Or is it because I coded incorrectly.

HTML

```
    <title> ENTER TITLE </title>

    </head>


    <body>

    <div id='page'> 
<!--All of Left Side Bar Contents -->

<div class="swrap">     
 <div id="logo">
        <img src="img/logo_green.png">
        </div>



    <div id="about">
    <aside class="tlb"><p>About Us</p></aside>
        <p>Welcome. We are Author, nulla mauris odio, vehicula in, condimentum sit amet, tempus id, metus. Donec at nisi sit amet felis blandit posuere. Aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
        </div>

    <div id="services">
    <aside class="tlb"><p>Services</p></aside>  
        <ul>
        <li>Web Site Dev and Applications </li>
        <div class='hr'></div>  
        <li>CMS</li>
            <div class='hr'></div>
        <li>Digital Branding and Industry</li>
            <div class='hr'></div>
        <li>UI Design</li>
            <div class='hr'></div>
        <li>Social Media</li>
        <div class='hr'></div>
        <li>User Experience</li>
            <div class='hr'></div>
        <li>Creative Ingenuity</li>
        </ul>       </div>  

    </div>

<!-- Center Content ( main header, main image )     -->
    <div class="mwrap">

<!--        Main Nav Above Slider -->


            <nav class='mnav'>
     <ul>
         <li class="m1"><a href='#'>home</a></li>
         <li class="m2"><a href='#'>Author</a></li>
         <li  class="m3"><a href='#'>work</a></li>
         <li class="m4"><a href='#'>clients</a></li>
         <li class="m5"><a href='#'>contact</a></li>
            </ul>
     </nav>

        <div id="fimg">
        <img src="img/fumic_naslovna.jpg">
        </div>

        <div id="featart">
        <article>
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
        <p> Nulla mauris odio, vehicula in, condimentum sit amet, tempus id, metus. Donec at nisi sit amet felis blandit posuere. Aliquam erat volutpat. Cras lobortis orci in quam porttitor cursus. Aenean dignissim. Curabitur facilisis sem at nisi laoreet placerat. Duis sed ipsum ac nibh mattis feugiat. Proin sed purus. Vivamus lectus ipsum, rhoncus sed, scelerisque sit amet, ultrices in, dolor. Aliquam vel magna non nunc ornare bibendum. Sed libero. Maecenas at est. Vivamus ornare, felis et luctus dapibus, lacus leo convallis diam, eget dapibus augue arcu eget arcu.</p>
        </article>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div id="rwrap">
        <div class="rfc">
            <aside class="tlb">Featured Clients</aside>
            <p> Nulla mauris odio, vehicula in, condimentum sit amet, tempus id, metus. Donec at nisi sit amet felis blandit posuere. Aliquam erat volutpat. Cras lobortis orci in quam porttitor cursus.</p>
            <div class='hr'></div>
            <p> Nulla mauris odio, vehicula in, condimentum sit amet, tempus id, metus. Donec at nisi sit amet felis blandit posuere. Aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
            </div>

        </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
background-image: url(img/brown.jpg);   
background-repeat:no-repeat;
-webkit-background-size:cover;
-moz-background-size:cover;
-o-background-size:cover;
background-size:cover;
background-position:center;
padding-bottom:12%;
color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: large;
    text-align: left;
}

* {
border-radius: 1px; 
}

#page {

margin: 30px 25%;
width: auto;
/*  width should be 50% ... 25% on each side, 50% in middle, centered!*/
border: 2px solid black;    
}


/*Left Content Begins ------------------ */

.swrap {
    width: 23%;
    display:inline-block;
/*1% margin on each side    */
    margin-top: 100px;
}

#logo {
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);   
}

#about {
margin: 3px 0;  
background-color: rgba(89, 194, 141, 1);
padding: 5%;    
}

#about aside {
margin-left: -6% !important;    

}

#services {
background-color:rgba(66, 161, 75, .96);
padding: 2%;
    margin: 3px 0;  
}

.tlb {
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
width: 75%;
margin: -10px 0 0 -2% !important;
padding-left: 4%;
}

/*Middle Content Begins ------------------ */

.mwrap {
    width: 48%; 
    margin: 0 auto;
/*1% margin on each side for .mwrap*/
    display:inline-block;

}


.mnav ul {
list-style:none;    

}

.mnav ul li {
display: inline;
font-size: large;
font-weight:bold;
padding: 2px 2%;
border-radius: 1px;

}

.mnav ul li a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;

}

.m1 {background-color:rgba(46, 206, 87, 1); }
.m2 {background-color: rgba(39, 197, 80, 1); }
.m3 {background-color: rgba(70, 182, 99, 1); }
.m4 {background-color: rgba(64, 164, 90, 1);}
.m5 {background-color: rgba(63, 140, 83, 1); }

.mnav ul li:active {
background-color:none !important;   

}

.mnav li:hover {
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.3);

}

#fimg {
width: 100%;    

}
#fimg img {
width: 100%;    
}

#featart {
margin-top: -10px;  
background-color:   rgba(64, 164, 90, .9);
padding: 1% 1%;     

}


/*Right Content Begins ------------------ */

#rwrap {
width: 23%;
display:inline-block;   
/*1% margin on each side    */

}


.rfc {
    background-color:rgba(66, 161, 75, .96);
padding: 2%;


}

.rfc .tlb {
margin-top: 9px !important; 
margin-left: -2.3% !important;
border-top-right-radius: 2px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to use position relative `position: relative; bottom: [how ever many pixels]`
A better (and later much more flexible) way is to change you HTML structure a little bit.
If I were building this site I'd break it into two wrapping divs with three column divs under each of them like here:

```
 <div class="header">
      <div class="left-column">
           <img id="logo" src="img/logo.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="middle-column">
           <ul class="nav"></ul>
      </div>
      <div class="right-column">
           Put content here if you want it
      </div>
 </div>

 <div class="content">
      <div class="left-column">
           Content in left column
      </div>
      <div class="middle-column">
           Content in middle
      </div>
      <div class="right-column">
           Content on right
      </div>
 </div>
```

Now, use CSS to float those columns just like you did before. The difference with this is you can define a height for the header and the logo and navigation will be much easier to align as they are separate from the other columns.

If you want to get more technical check out CSS Flexbox, it would work well here.
http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/holy-grail/

Comment: I've been told to avoid floats, and with my experience, they suck when it comes to being responsive.
Floats move up/down when resizing.
BUT -- this is my limited experience.

I did this with inline-block.

Yea it looks interesting.
Would you have an example of what you're suggesting?

Comment: It probably is a good idea to use display: inline-block or other methods.
My example is really the same thing you are doing, only I'm splitting the above elements and the content elements to make positioning more fluid.
But again, check out flex box, super cool, no floats or inline-blocks needed. I just used it on a recent project.

Comment: Hey sorry, I couldn't put my comment into words ha, kept editing, 

Flexbox looks interesting, would you have an example of what you're suggesting?

Comment: Suggesting with Flex Box or the HTML I posted?

Comment: sorry, yea the Flex Box.

Comment: Yeah, check out this link. http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/holy-grail/ It's a little complicated but works well once you get the hang of it.

Answer (score 0):

set 
a position: relative;
bottom: X px;